# Mostrar exepcion en error provider desde clase validación

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me he creado una clase con tres métodos para validar los TextBox de mis formularios.

1. Solo texto
2. Solo números
3. No vacíos

En cada método tengo un catch exeption error, al método que necesito lo llamo desde el evento KeyPress del TextBox, pero no se como puedo llamar a esta exepcion en mi control error provider de mi formulario, en caso de que por ejemplo solo tenga que insertar letras llamo al método solo letras pero si el usuario intenta ingresar un numero u otro dígito que se muestre la exepcion en el error provider.

Esta es mi clase con mis métodos:

```
class Validations
{

    //Metodo para validar solo letras
    public void onlyChars(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string err = "";
        try
        {
            if(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            err = "Only accpet letters.";
        }
    }


    //Metodo para validar solo numeros
    public void onlyNumbers(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        
    {
        string err = "";
        try
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = "Only accept numbers.";
        }
    }


    //Metodo para validar que no este vacio el text box
    public void validateNulls(KeyPressEventArgs e)

    {
        string err = "";
        try
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = "Please fill text box.";
        }
    }
}
```

En mi formulario:

```
public partial class FormNewApp : Form
{
    Validations validation = new Validations();
    public FormNewApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtNameApp_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        validation.onlyChars(e);
        //errorProvider1.SetError(validation.onlyChars(Exception));
    }
}
```

EDICION:

```
public class Support
{
    private static Support instance = null;

    public static Support GetSupport()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Support();
        return instance;
    }

    public void soloLetrasConAdvertencia(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = "";

        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //MessageBox.Show("No se permiten numeros", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //error = "No insert numbers!";
            error = "No isert numbers";

        }
        else
        {
            if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                error = "Only letters";
            }
            else
            {
                if (char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    error = "No insert symbols!";

                }
                else
                {
                    if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        //MessageBox.Show("No se permiten espacios en blanco", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        error = "No null space";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
                        {
                            e.Handled = false;
                            error = "Only letters";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                            {
                                e.Handled = false;
                                error = "Only letters";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                                {
                                    e.Handled = false;
                                    error = "Only letters";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    e.Handled = true;
                                    //MessageBox.Show("Solo letras o numeros", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    error = "Only letters";

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
```

Usando este código anterior recién editado , como paso el error al teclear números o letras cuando no se necesite al control error provider de mi formulario, agregue en cada if else, el error y en la penúltima linea retorno el error pero me marca un error.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
**Error CS0127  Since 'Support.soloLetrasConAdvertencia(object, KeyPressEventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression**

Saludos

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario hacer manejo de excepciones para esto, agregar try catch para manejar una simple validación de textBox solo agrega complejidad.
Si solo quiere crear una clase que te brinde soporte para TextBox,ComboBox,label,etc. Solo deberías crear una clase de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Support //creas una clase Support la cual se va a encargar de las validaciones en general
    {
        private static Support instance = null; //declaras una variable instance para aplicar el patrón singleton, el cual te va a permitir tener una unica instancia global de esta.

        public static Support GetSupport() // creas este método el cual crea o retorna la única instancia
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Support();
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Dentro de esta clase creas un método `soloLetras()`, este método no permite ingresar letras en un TextBox, pero no avisa de esto:

```
public void soloLetras(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
            else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = false;
            else if (char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true; // true para evitar el ingreso
            else if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
            else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = false;// false para permitir el ingreso
            else if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = false;
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Si necesitas que retorne algún valor o que avise por ventana, debes hacer que retorne un string y agregar un return en cada if-else, te dejo un ejemplo utilizando un MessageBox.
Este método avisa que solo permite letras:

```
 public void soloLetrasConAdvertencia(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("No se permiten numeros", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("No se permiten espacios en blanco", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
                            {
                                e.Handled = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                                {
                                    e.Handled = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
                                    {
                                        e.Handled = false;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        e.Handled = true;
                                        MessageBox.Show("Solo letras o numeros", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ahora para llamar a estos métodos solo debes ir al evento KeyPress del textBox que deseas validar y le haces doble click, esto va a crear el código necesario para el evento y dentro de este bloque pones este código:

```
Support.GetSupport().soloLetras(sender,e); // y envias el sender y e que fueron creados automáticamente por el IDE
```

Solo a modo de agregar info, te recomiendo crear un método que valide si es letra o numero lo que agrego en el textBox, ya que el evento KeyPress no evita que tu puedas copiar datos al textBox.

Comment: En la llamada del metodo en el evento KeyPress tengo que importar alguna libreria?
Me muestra un error "The name 'Support' does not exist in the current context.
@Franco Torres
private void txtNameApp_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Support.GetSupport().soloLetras(sender, e);
        }

Comment: es porque no creaste el objeto Support, si implementaste el patrón singleton lo deberías ver, si no deberías hacer Support sup = new Support(); O hacer un new de la clase que creaste para validar, si esto se te dificulta solo copia y pega el método soloLetras() en la clase que tiene el textBox y llámalo desde el evento, así lo deberías ver.

Comment: Usando tu codigo me funciona, pero no quisiera usar MessageBox quisiera usar el control provider de mi formulario. Agregue en cada If else el error string y debo retornarlo al final del código, ahí me marca un error que agregue en la edición de la pregunta. Y como llamo ese error desde mi formulario? @Franco Torres

Comment: Fijate que en la firma del metodo yo lo declaro void porque me manejo con MessageBox, en tu caso que buscas retornar una cadena, tenes que declararlo string, ya que un void no puede retornar nada. Deberia ser Public string soloLetras(...). Otra cosa, los mensajes de error solo van en donde e.Handled es igual a True, ya que en donde dice false son caracteres permitidos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede ayudar:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = Validations.onlyChars(e);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            MessageBox.Show(error);

        if (!e.Handled)
            label1.Text += e.KeyChar;
    }
}

public class Validations
{

    //Metodo para validar solo letras
    public static string onlyChars(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;

        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = false;
        else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = false;
        else if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = false;
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            error = "Only accpet letters!";
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

> Las funciones como `onlyChars` deben declararse como estáticas

No es una solucion limpia

Comment: Para detectar letras y números me funciona bien tu código, pero para validar que no existan TextBox vacios en o los formularios que modificación seria necesaria en el método?
if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))@sunriax